# Spring, XML beans call Annotation beans when app start

Tags: spring, annotations

I have one Annotation bean with some methods. It works fine.

```
public @Controller("adminController") class AdminController {

...
private @Autowired AdminDAO adminDAO;

public void resetTemporalList() {

    System.out.println("HE SIDO EJECUTADO.");

    this.adminDAO.resetTemporalRegisters();
}
```

...

}

Now, I am integrating one quartz task. But I am load it with XML definition beans that call previus annotation bean.

```
<bean id="resetTemporalRegisters" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="adminController" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="resetTemporalList" />
    <property name="concurrent" value="false" />
</bean>
```

Whan I start my app appear next error.

***Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'adminController' is defined***

I believe the problem is that Spring load XML beans first, after Annotation beans, then in this moment "adminController" bean not exits...

How Can I fix it?

**SOLVED IT!!**

Problem was in I put xml bean definitions in applicationContext.xml.

Answer (score 0):

No, XML and annotations integrate fine, but do you actually have the component scanning code in your XML?

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.yourcompany.yourapp"/>
```

See: [4.10 Classpath scanning and managed components](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-classpath-scanning)

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of guessing: your controller is defined in child application context created by Spring MVC while you `resetTemporalRegisters` job in main application context (parent). Child context can access beans from parent context but not the other way around.

This raises important question: why is your business logic trying to call a method of a controller? These methods should be called only be the MVC framework. Can't you just call

```
this.adminDAO.resetTemporalRegisters();
```

directly from your job?

```
<bean id="resetTemporalRegisters" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
  <property name="targetObject" ref="adminDAO" />
  <property name="targetMethod" value="resetTemporalRegisters" />
  <property name="concurrent" value="false" />
</bean>
```

`adminDAO` is probably defined in parent context, so you can access it easily.

Comment: adminDAO@Repository extends baseDAO@Repository, I created one new annotation @Parent for this. With your suggest I get same error. "Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'adminDAO' is defined"